# Best Resources for a new DIY'er Getting Started?

Tags: lawn, landscaping, planning

My wife & I recently purchased a new house and while the backyard isn't a total mess, it needs some work.  Both because the prior owner was elderly with limited abilities, but also because we want to make it a space we really enjoy.

Some of the major things:

- The lawn is very uneven.
- The yard is a mix of grass & clover.
- There are various pockets of shrubbery that's overgrown, in particular one area we'd like to return to simple grass (so we could use it for socializing, grilling, etc.)

I know one option is to hire a landscape architect, but for now we'd rather keep it simple & do it ourselves.  (Learning would be part of the fun, enable us to tweak it, and if we do get an architect, we'd have a better sense of what we want.)

The thing is, where to start!

Any experienced hands have suggestions on must-read books, websites or any resources we should avail ourselves off?  (I know planning will be an important step.)

Comment: Bill, What's wrong with starting here?! On a Q&A site like this, it's best to ask very specific questions about problems you are encountering. We try not to create collections of links or become a search engine just to send folks elsewhere. Search is the lifeblood of this site — and if someone is searching for the "removing clover from lawns", we sure would like them to find ***this*** site without becoming just another stop between the user and what they are searching for. We're here to provide definitive answers to questions about gardening. Ask specific questions; we'll be glad to help you!

Comment: Fair enough!  I didn't want to come across as the novice unwilling to even do basic homework before asking for help.  :)